# MVC pattern with only one controller class?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm learning about MVC patterns, specifically with php, and have read some great tutorials. I've managed to get up a basic stricture that works. Just for fun, I started experimenting with how the controllers, models and views interact and ended up having one controller class which creates a model/view depending on the requested page. So I just instantiate this controller in the main index.php and pass it the url values. For example, "mysite/blog/recent" would have the controller include (and instantiate) the "models/blog/recent.php" file containing a model and the corresponding view in the views folder. My question is whether there's an advantage to having actual controller classes for each section of the website instead of just seperating the models into different folders (i.e "blog" ) and loading them with one controller class?

Comment: Model is a layer, not a class or object. And view are not simple templates. I do not know what tutorials you used, but sounds like they have been filled with crap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a certain point where making decisions regarding MVC becomes a little less cut and dry. For a very small (and simple) site, you may only need one controller that does all your work for you, pulling data from models and constructing the views. You can certainly construct your MVC architecture so that all the models and views are instantiated by a single controller, but of course, this quickly falls apart once you get to a site of even remote complexity.

My recommendation is to make your controllers conceptually separated in the same way you might design an application in a modular way. I would have a BlogController with all my blog methods and page serving, a ContactController, a PortfolioController, all inheriting from a master PageController in order to make sure that when the complexity of these different parts of my site expanded, I could maintain them without having a big ol' SoupController.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are using an MVC style and get in the habit of making classes for things that can be organized as objects (tire.wheel.spoke), then you’ll be fine.

Start small—-Rome wasn’t built in a day. You’ll have your first controller, then maybe as you add more features you’ll add another one. I’ve always liked the idea of writing an API that calls on your controllers from the beginning since many modern websites eventually have to do this anyway and doing it from the beginning forces you to organize your controllers and simplify your command structures.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate the quick and helpful replies.

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer "solved" your problem, please mark it as such!